# Athen table specifying table properties using terraform script

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-athena

Some of my athena tables are configured to partition based on a column called `partition_date`. When viewing the DDL of those tables, I see a number of table properties.

```
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='json', 
  'compressionType'='gzip', 
  'groupFiles'='inPartition', 
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.partition_date.format'='yyyy-MM-dd', 
  'projection.partition_date.range'='2020-07-01,2025-12-31', 
  'projection.partition_date.type'='date', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

My question is: how do I implement these table properties using terraform script?

I have tried `parameters` [field](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.18.0/docs/resources/glue_catalog_table#parameters) but no luck and received error from terraform planning:

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│ 
│   on glue.tf line 19, in resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "gu_play_and_earn_prod":
│   19:       projection.partition_date.type    = "date"
│ 
│ A managed resource "projection" "partition_date" has not been declared in the root module.
```

Comment: Can you add the code you have to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to below example using which you should be able to pass these properties with your `glue_catalog_table`. [Here](https://github.com/DMW2151/tf-aws-svc-logs-athena/blob/655f8837ec0f14dde38b9692b7d811f33e6e56f6/src_alb_athena.tf#L18) is a full example of the same.

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "alb_logs_src" {

  // General
  name          = var.alb_logs_tbl_name
  database_name = var.athena_db_name
  table_type    = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"
  description   = "Application Load Balancer (ALB) logs From ${local.alb_src_s3_path}"

  // Table Properties
  parameters = {

    // General
    EXTERNAL                      = "TRUE"
    "has_encrypted_data"          = "false"
    "projection.enabled"          = tostring(var.enable_projected_partitions)
    "partition_filtering.enabled" = tostring(var.enable_partition_filtering)

    // Partition Projection - Date
    "projection.date.type"   = "date"
    "projection.date.range"  = "2022/01/01,NOW"
    "projection.date.format" = "yyyy/MM/dd"

    // Partition Projection - Region - All Active Regions
    "projection.region.type"   = "enum"
    "projection.region.values" = join(", ", var.organization_enabled_regions)

    // Partition Projection - Accounts in Org
    "projection.account_id.type"   = "enum"
    "projection.account_id.values" = join(", ", var.organization_account_ids != "" ? var.organization_account_ids : [data.aws_caller_identity.current.id])

    // Storage Location
    "storage.location.template" = "${local.alb_src_s3_path}AWSLogs/$${account_id}/elasticloadbalancing/$${region}/$${date}/"

  }

  // Partition Indexes
  partition_index {
    index_name = "date_partition_index"
    keys       = ["date"]
  }

  // Partition Columns
  partition_keys {
    name    = "account_id"
    type    = "string"
    comment = "The ID of the network interface for which the traffic is recorded"
  }
  ......
  ......
  ......
```